# How to start a browser using supervisord?

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I'm trying to start browser(firefox) using supervisord.
This is the part of my conf file.

```
[program:firefox]
user=root
enivornment=DISPLAY=":0"
command=/usr/bin/firefox
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Now when i start my supervisord , firefox won't open though it can be found in ps aux | grep firefox.
I'm using Xubuntu.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a different user than `root`. The following is working: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/m9wX9VzT3Y

Comment: And try restarting your computer ...

Comment: For me, the solution was quite the opposite, I had to specify the user as `root` just because the other user did not have enough permissions. The error messages are not quite helpful either. Mainly is a permissions issue.